# Scheduled MS Access macro to run query and export to CSV

Tags: ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to get a windows Scheduled Task to open up MS Access DB (.mdb) which has an AutoExec macro that runs some queries and then exports it to a .csv replacing the .csv file that is already there.

From the command prompt I can run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "/Path to my Access DB"
```

and everything works perfectly. Access opens up, runs the query, and replaces the .csv with new data from the query.

When I try to do this with a Scheduled Task access just deletes the .csv file without ever replacing it and returns the error "the operator or administrator has refused the request".

Any ideas? I was looking for a quick way to get the data but I feel like I might be better off just writing some python to connect to Access.

Comment: So you are running query objects called by macro? What do these queries do? Perhaps construct the query statements in VBA and run with `CurrentDb.Execute "sql statement here"`. That's what I do.

Comment: Trying to replicate issue. What is your code for the export?

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. My application path does not have `root` and I have `Office14`.

Comment: Sorry I got pulled away. I was running the script to start access, run the query and export macro then close.


set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.Visible = False
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("path to .mdb")
accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "XdLaborExport"
accessApp.Quit
set accessApp = nothing

I'm going to move it over to VBA when I get a chance.

Comment: Edit your question to show new info so it is easier to read. Is that your original code? I am not able to replicate issue. I tested the TaskScheduler with the command you posted and an AutoExec macro. The csv is exported and Access remains open.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to return to this problem this week and finally found the solution.

The problem came down to the scheduled task. It was a local machine permissions issue and running the task with the correct domain that solved it.

First to fix the local machine permission I had to make sure that the user running the task had "Log on as a batch job" permissions. 
Found at **Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> Local Security Policy\Local Policies\User Rights Assignments -> "Log on as a batch job"**

Second, because I was on a domain the schedule task had to be explicitly created by the domain user. I had to manually find the user on the domain during the creation of the task and remove the user that was auto populated by the task scheduled creation wizard.