# Schedule export of Access query

Tags: vba, database, csv

I have this similar problem as this question asked a couple years ago, [Scheduled MS Access macro to run query and export to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074754/scheduled-ms-access-macro-to-run-query-and-export-to-csv).

I followed his steps to correct but, still getting prompted to save over existing file.  The other issue I am having is the task is not running in task scheduler, the macro runs when I manually open Access though.  I feel comfortable creating the macro in Access, but getting lost when I read other post about going the VBA route.  Do I put my SQL for the macro in Access VBA with CurrentDb.Execute "sql statement here", I still need to schedule in task scheduler though right?

I am very new to VBA and have never even run one, tried entering some code but got overwhelmed.

Would this be a good substitute?

```
    Function AutoExec()  
On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err 
    
    Kill "P:\Jarett\smtest1.csv" 
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "po_detail3", "MS-DOSText(*.txt)", "P:\Jarett\smtest1.csv", True, "", 1,   acExportQualityPrint  

AutoExec_Exit:  
    Exit Function 

AutoExec_Err: 
    MsgBox Error$  
    Resume AutoExec_Exit  

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the function to export the data, then create a macro called "AutoExec" to call your function when the database is opened.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272945/exporting-a-query-result-into-a-text-file-using-vba-ms-access) describes how to write a function to export the results of a query to a text file.

If you need to delete the output file if it already exists, add this code immediately before you run the query.

```
If Dir(Filename) <> "" Then Kill Filename
```

Access has no scheduling capability itself, so yes, you still need to use task scheduler.

**In response to latest comment:**

You could schedule a task to delete the file. Hey if it works, it works, but this is just as delete-y.

```
Function AutoExec() 

    Dim FileName As String
    
    FileName = "P:\Jarett\123.csv"

    If Dir(Filename) <> "" Then Kill Filename

    On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err      

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Smtest123 Export Specification", "po_detail3", Filename, True, ""     

    DoCmd.Quit acSave   

AutoExec_Exit:     
    Exit Function  

AutoExec_Err:     
    MsgBox Error$     
    Resume AutoExec_Exit  

End
```

Comment: So this goes in the beginning of the SQL part of the macro?

Comment: No it is VBA code should go in the function immediately before the data is exported.

Comment: I converted the macro to VBA but the code above keeps giving me errors                           If Dir (P:\Jarett\smtest.csv) <> "" Then Kill P:\Jarett\smtest.csv

Comment: When all else fails, check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/kill-statement) (and pray there are examples).

Comment: Not sure if this is the best method but got something to work, `Function AutoExec()
On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Smtest123 Export Specification", "po_detail3", "P:\Jarett\123.csv", True, ""
    DoCmd.Quit acSave


AutoExec_Exit:
    Exit Function

AutoExec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume AutoExec_Exit

End Function`

Comment: Then just added a task to the task scheduler to delete the file before I open access